# how to plot time stamp data from excel by matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, date, plot, timestamp

I have an excel file that contains 2 thousands of time vs amplitude data sets. Time cell is A and amplitude cell is B. The data looks like this:

2/23/2012 3:12  -69.4

2/23/2012 3:13  -70.3

2/23/2012 3:14  -73.3

2/23/2012 3:15  -75.4

2/23/2012 3:16  -78.1

2/23/2012 3:17  -80.1

How can I plot the amplitude values with respect to the time stamp in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
%%// FILENAME
filename = 'sid.xls';

%%// OPTION 1: If there is a lot of data, XTickLaabels and XTicks would clutter up.
%%// To Avoid that, define the number of XTickLabels needed, 
%%// otherwise set it as NaN to use all x-data.
XTickLabel_count = 3;

%%// OPTION 2:  If you would like to show the time only with dates
time_only = false;

%%// OPTION 3:  If you would like to show the XTickLabels as 90 degrees rotated
XTickRot = false;

%%// Read in data
[num,text1,raw] = xlsread(filename);

%%// Account for 12AM times, which are not read in text1. Append that data.
split1 = regexp(text1,'\s','Split');
zero_times = cellfun(@numel, split1)==1;
text1(cellfun(@numel, split1)==1) = mat2cell([char(text1(zero_times)) repmat(' 00:00:00',nnz(zero_times),1)],ones(1,nnz(zero_times)));

%%// Get the time only data without dates
split1 = regexp(text1,'\s','Split');
split_text = vertcat(split1{:});
time_text = split_text(:,2);

%%// Use the time only data for XTickLabels
if time_only
    text1 = time_text;
end

%%// Select few XTickLabels from the entire X-data or whole respectively
%%// and store as text2
if ~isnan(XTickLabel_count)
    XTickIntv = round(numel(text1)/XTickLabel_count);
    text2 = cell(size(text1));
    text2(1:XTickIntv:end)=text1(1:XTickIntv:end);
else
    text2 = text1;
end

%%// Plot
figure,plot(num)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',text2, 'XTick',1:numel(text2))
if XTickRot
    xticklabel_rotate([],90,text2);
end
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0]) %%// Remove XTicks but keep XTicklabels

return;
```

**Note:** This code uses [**`XTICKLABEL_ROTATE from Mathworks File-exchange`**](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate)

**Approach 1:** Using `XTickLabel_count = 3` `time_only = false` and `XTickRot = false`

[image]

**Approach 2:** Using `XTickLabel_count = 5` `time_only = true` and `XTickRot = false`

[image]

**Approach 3:** Using `XTickLabel_count = 10` `time_only = true` and `XTickRot = true`

[image]

Comment: Hi,  
When I plot it in my MATLAB reading the excel file, I get this from your 1st approach:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j8noqt&s=8#.U0SoA71lfDc
see the plot created some dark lines instead of date time ticks.

The second approach plots this:  
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15xqree&s=8

See there is no time mark just some integer values. 
Your third approach plots something like the first approach + it also shows an error message in line:4

What is the problem here?

Comment: Hi,
Here is my raw excel file. Can you tell me what the problem with plotting with your code is?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByntE7ZqdSzoNkRhb0p3ckl0Mzg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user3511734 Check out the edited codes and make sure you pick up the script to rotate the `XTickLabels` from [here](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate)

Comment: @user3511734 Wondering if this worked for you, because the plots in the answer are from your data.